# SQL foreign key on primary key or unique column

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys, primary-key, unique

Suppose I have two tables, table A and table B, and that table A has the following columns:

```
COLUMNS (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE)
```

I want to create a column in table B which references a row of table A using a foreign key.
Most of the time when I look up a row in table B I will also want to retrieve the name field in the row of table A that it references.
Speed of lookups (but not insertions) is a concern.

Would it be better to use the primary key of table A as the foreign key and then use a JOIN to bring in the value of the name field, or would it be better to use the name field as the foreign key so that that data is already present when looking up a row in table B?

Comment: If you're storing the name value in TableB then what is the point in having TableA in the first place?

Comment: name has different semantics in table A and table B; in table A it's the name of a different object, associated with the row in table B

Comment: OK, but what I'm getting at is you need to use the `id`, otherwise having a lookup table is pointless.

Comment: Oh sorry I understand. In the real tables, table A contains more columns, and it is referenced from other tables as well

Comment: **It would be a terrible design to use the Name in tableB as a FK.** this would duplicate data and if you ever need to change the name you now have a real mess.  use the PK.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to give you proper advice. You have two candidate keys. If `name` is not stable then perhaps better to use the surrogate `ID`. However, if there is a business rule, say, that the `name` in A cannot be the same as a `name` in B then perhaps you'd want to reference `name` if your DBMS only supports row level `CHECK` constraints.

Comment: @onedaywhen, I can't imagine ever wanting to join on a `VARCHAR(200)`

Comment: @KM. I can't imagine ever wanting to eat peanut butter in significant quantities but I say that only because I've actually tried it at least 10 times.

Comment: @onedaywhen, it doesn't really matter if we have more info or not, it is still a bad idea  joining on long stings is not recommended for performance reasons. using "data" for FKs is a bad idea, when the data changes it is hard to update it (when you update one row the FK breaks and you get an error, you will need to insert a new parent row, update the child to the new parent, then delete the old parent).

Comment: @KM.: who said the string are long? Who said the string ever change? What problem was `ON UPDATE CASCADE` invented to solve? Is 'bad idea' subjective? Can 'poor performance' be demonstrated in comments on SO?

Comment: @onedaywhen, ha ha, knock yourself out, go join your varchar(200) strings.  A join on a long string column "Name" wouldn't pass a code review anywhere I've worked.

Comment: In this instance, name is not a candidate key because it is nullable.

Comment: @sqlvogel: that's a moot point. In Standard SQL a nullable column with a `UNIQUE` constraint would allow only one null, therefore it would indeed be a key. Any other conclusion would make for a far less interesting question ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen, In standard SQL nulls are *ignored* for the purposes of checking the UNIQUE constraint. Therefore multiple nulls could be present in the Name column since NOT NULL hasn't been specified. Any attribute that permits nulls (and duplicates) certainly cannot be a candidate key. I accept that this was probably an oversight on mskel's part. Perhaps mskel really intended to specify NOT NULL for the Name column but the fact remains that he didn't do so. Details like that make all the difference.

Comment: @KM. let's name the OP's table 'Products' and introduce a second table `UKProducts (id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Products (id), name VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE)` and a business rule that for a given `id` the `UKProduct.name` cannot be the same as `Product.name`. Some code will be needed to include a search condition that compares two "varchar(200) strings": if a join would fail your code review, what would pass (a `WHERE` clause? A `UNION`, `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT`?) and why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sqlvogel: oops, I remembered wrong and got that completely the wrong way around. I am in complete agreement with your comments. p.s. I'd have been more vigilant if you were still using your real name ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the name can change. Maybe someone finds a better name or there was a typo in the name that must be corrected. Whereas the PK should never change. Always use the ID as FK. This is how a lookup table works.

If you use an identity column as PK, the IDs will be generated automatically and cannot be changed. It is mostly a good idea to have a meaningless PK. Meaningful columns tend to be subject of edits.

Answer (score 2):

it will be better to use the primary key of table A as the foreign key and then use a JOIN to bring in the value of the name field other wise just put everything in table B

Answer (score 0):

In your example "name" is a nullable column so it is not a candidate key. A foreign key constraint is supposed to reference a candidate key (e.g. "Id" in this case). I recommend you either change the table to make "name" non-nullable or reference Id instead.

Nullable UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY constraints in SQL can be implemented in different ways in different database products. Their meaning is sometimes ambiguous and the results of using them are often contradictory and probably won't match reality.

(It may be that allowing nulls was just an oversight in your CREATE TABLE statement - in which case I suggest you amend the question).